# Replace backspace with strikethrough in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, editor, tinymce

I am using TinyMce editor in my webpage. Where whenever user enters some text, he should not be able to delete the text... (Disabling the backspace Key) or else if he uses backspace key text should be strikethough (change functionality of backspace). Is there a function in tinymce to do this?

```
if (((e.which === 8 || e.keyCode === 8))||(e.which === 46 || e.keyCode === 46)) { // Delete key
          // Do something
          var rng = ed.selection.getRng(true);
        var txt = rng.startContainer.textContent;
          fncAddText(txt.substring(rng.startOffset - 1, rng.startOffset));
          handled = true;
        }
      if (handled) {
        tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(e);
      }      
    function fncAddText(txt) {
        var theText="<del>"+txt+"</del>";
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceReplaceContent',false,theText);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there exists nothing like this in the code shipped with tinymce nor do i know of a plugin elsewhere with this functionality. But you are free to create something like this yourself.

Comment: do you mean overriding functionality of backspace?? @Thariama

Comment: yes, exactly that's what i meant. have alook at the onKeyDown tinymce vent to filter out the backspace keystroke

Comment: Thank you @Thariama, I am working on it. I am sure it will work. Thank you once again.

Comment: yyou may thank me using the upvode arrow (and of course accepting my answer) :)  if you encounter any problems let me know

Comment: I will definitely do that @Thariama

Comment: I have added piece of code here. But the strikethrough text is getting appended to the current text but not getting replaced and also the text is not getting strikethrough in order(Properly)

where did i go wrong?

@Thariama

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle.

but is it possible to do without selecting the text. 

assume that user have entered some text and cursor is at the end.
When he presses backspace from last character by character should be striked off and position of cursor should be at the end of text again.

This is what I was trying for. but failed to do so.